# Java program output handle

Tags: java

I want to run a compiled Java/C code by an external Java program. Problem is compiled Java/C code directs all input and output to standard devices but I want that external program to handle its input and output in real-time, like a user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Runtime and Process Class

```
//Sample Code
Runtime compileRuntime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process compileProcess = compileRuntime.exec("javac MyClass.java");
```

and the returned Process class object has an input and output stream.

see this for more details.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html